# Getting an unexpected T_STRING when trying to retrieve data and store as variable

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, database

I am unable to make $firstname equal to $row['Firstname']. The same with Lastname too.

```
$locationsQuery='select Firstname, Lastname, from locations where
username=$username;
 $results = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $locationsQuery, array($desiredusername));
 while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($results))
 {
 $firstname = $row['Firstname'];
 $lastname = $row['Lastname'];
 }
```

Comment: Is this copy/paste from the actual code? If so, you're missing a closing `'` after your query.

Comment: Missing single quote `'` for your `$locationsQuery` variable

Comment: Look at the highlighting..

Comment: Your query also is open to SQL injections and invalid, strings need to be quoted.

Comment: oh my gosh such a stupid error thank you

Comment: @Z.Sow You should delete the question since it isnt a programming issue.

Comment: question's like these do not improve Stack's Q&A's and there are far too many already asked and in the process of deletion.

Comment: there is also another "off-topic" syntax error; the trailing comma in the last column, as well as an unquoted string literal.

Answer (score -1):

You are missing a `'` at the end of the first line containing `$locationsQuery`, in front of `;`

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174389/should-we-answer-or-comment-on-a-typo-question

Comment: if you're going to go after an off-topic syntax/typo error, at the very least.. .get them all